# Running Time of a Statement with Array

Tags: arrays, time

So I am actually having a hard time in counting or measure the running time of this code. It's actually composed of consecutive statements.

```
for(x=0; x<n; x++)//x=0 is 1, x<n is n+1, x++ is n, to sum up, it's 2n+2
    arr[x]=0; //How about an array? How do I compute a running time on an array?

for(x=0; x<n; x++) //x=0 is, x<n is (n-i)+1, y++ is (n-x)

    for(y=0;y<n;y++) //y=0 is zero, y<n is (n-y)+1, y++ is (n-j)
      arr[x]+=arr[y]+x+y; //and I am having a hard time on this line,
      //but I do know that += is 1, since there are two + sign,
      then that's two right? Then how about arr[x] and arr[y]?
```

My problem is within the comments, how do we measure running time for arrays? Like a[x], a[y].

Comment: What do you mean by "running time on an array"?  All the arithmetic operations, assignments, and array access (e.g. `arr[x]`) are constant time.  The time complexity of the code is correctly assessed by Prathik in his answer below.  Also, there's a simple closed-form expression: `arr[x] = x*n + (x+1)*(n-1)*(n)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic complexity of the above algo is O(n^2). The main contributor is 2 for loops. In the nested for loop you iterate n times for each x = [0, n]. Also you can ignore the constants when computing the complexity because when n becomes very large the contribution of constants is negligible.